# Curve over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$

Tags: nt.number-theory

It is known by Mordell-Lang that the group of a curve over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ is abelian and finitely generated. Can it be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?
What about its zeta function?

Comment: An elliptic curve, I suppose you mean.  Yes, it can be infinite cyclic.  What do you want to know about the zeta function?

Comment: There are results by Douglas Ulmer.

Comment: e.g. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.1939.pdf Lecture 1, §12.